# Unable to connect to h2 database

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have been trying to integrate h2 DB with spring boot application and I am getting the following error when trying to connect from the h2-console

```
Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200]
```

I tried adding the following properties to the application.properties file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

It still does not seem to work.

This is how my build.gradle file looks like

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'

    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected if you replace the line

```
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'
```

with

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
```

in `build.gradle` if you make sure that the field JDBC URL in the login mask has the value `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`.

You get the correct `build.gradle` if you use the Spring Initializr and add

- Lombok
- Spring Data JPA
- H2 Database
- Spring Web

If you want to add dependencies to a project that was originally created with the Spring Initializr, it's usually a good idea to go back to https://start.spring.io/, add all dependencies, hit the Explore button, and copy & paste the generated `build.gradle` into the existing project.